# Service Object method breaking integration test Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, minitest

I've got an integration test with Rails 4.2 that works without a service object method, but has an error when I try to factor some logic out into a service object.  The error is "NameError: uninitialized constant LeadsController::SendEmailConfirmation"

This works with the test:

```
def create
  @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
  if @lead.save
    LeadMailer.email_confirmation(@lead).deliver_now
    flash[:success] = "Thank you for subscribing"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This doesn't work with the test:

```
def create
  @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
  if @lead.save
    SendEmailConfirmation.call(@lead) # This is the problem method
    flash[:success] = "Thank you for subscribing!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

send_email_confirmation.rb:

```
class SendEmailConfirmation

  def self.call(lead)
    LeadMailer.email_confirmation(lead).deliver_now
    lead.confirmation_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    lead.save
  end

end
```

It seems as though the service object itself works, but the test doesn't recognize the method.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you specify the absolute namespace for service object.

```
::SendEmailConfirmation.call(@lead) # Note the "::"
```